# Android, App doesn't start

Tags: android

as the name suggested, my app doesn't startup and debugger is focusing on this line.
The app doesn't create the UI and debugger is focusing on one particular line.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
enabled = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.enabled);
enabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);

flat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flat);
flat.setOnClickListener(this);

bass_boost = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.bass_boost);
bass_boost.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
bass_boost_label = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.bass_boost_label);

sliders[0] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_1);
slider_labels[0] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_1);
//More sliders



eq = new Equalizer (0, 0);//<----------------------------This line
if (eq != null)
  {
  eq.setEnabled (true);
  int num_bands = eq.getNumberOfBands();
  num_sliders = num_bands;
  short r[] = eq.getBandLevelRange();
  min_level = r[0];
  max_level = r[1];
  for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders && i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
    {
    int[] freq_range = eq.getBandFreqRange((short)i);
    sliders[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    slider_labels[i].setText (formatBandLabel (freq_range));
    }
  }
for (int i = num_sliders ; i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
  {
  sliders[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
  slider_labels[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }

bb = new BassBoost (0, 0);
if (bb != null)
  {
  }
else
  {
  bass_boost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  bass_boost_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

updateUI();
}
```

How can I start the app properly?

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: on which line it shows the error?

Comment: There is no error, it just tell me to Debug Current Instruction Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters
-priority: the priority level requested by the application for controlling the Equalizer engine. As the same engine can be shared by several applications, this parameter indicates how much the requesting application needs control of effect parameters. The normal priority is 0, above normal is a positive number, below normal a negative number.

-audioSession   system wide unique audio session identifier. The Equalizer will be attached to the MediaPlayer or AudioTrack in the same audio session.

I'm guessing 0 isn't a system wide unique identifier..

Edit: Check out the AudioFxDemo in the samples (sdk\samples\android-16\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media).

Snippet fron the sample:

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private Equalizer mEqualizer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_media_file_here);

    // Create the Equalizer object (an AudioEffect subclass) and attach it to our media player,
    // with a default priority (0).
    mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
    mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if I'm using AudioTrack? I'm trying to direct the sound from mic to speaker in real time while given the choice to filter the sound.

Comment: mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId ());

Comment: I did as you told, but now the debugger stops at 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //Audio, mic to speaker
  setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        initControls();
        mAudioThread = new AudioThread();
        mAudioThread.start();
        mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId());//<------this line
        mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);
        //end

Comment: 1) Read the docs 2) provide logcat output, showing at which line the error occurs isn't helpful at all! 3) Where do you instantiate your AudioTrack?

Comment: Sorry for giving unclear information. I instantiate my AudioTrack in my public class MainActivity.

Comment: But the use for my AudioTrack is in another class, would this affect the outcome?

Comment: You will have to pass it to the class where you need it.

Comment: No problem! Consider having a better username :) ppl will be more eager to answer your questions

Comment: Sorry, I still cant figure out whats the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a78gu8fhxdctdqj/Copy%20%282%29%20of%20AudioTest.zip
This is my source code, is it alright if you could take a look and instruct me on whats the error?